missing crypto module after installing pycryptodome
i'm trying to meke an AES-256 encryption program, but python says that pycryptodome is not installed
i already tryied to install pycryptodomex but still don't work, i tryed to reinstall completly pycryptodome unistalling the others packages but still don't work.
for now my code is only:
from crypto.Cipher import AES
from crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

from colorama import Fore

when i try to use the python command it say:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giova\Desktop\hash\AES-256.py", line 1, in <module>
    from crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crypto'

so i don't really know what to expect

So, first of all, you need to ensure pycryptodome is different from pycryptodomex. Secondly, the code you write from crypto.Cipher import AES is wrong, it should be from Crypto.Cipher import AES, the same applies below. If this still doesn't work properly, I recommend using JS for AES encryption. Node.js is well-suited for encryption.
